# Can fullcalendar setup not to overlap a fixed navbar or header

Tags: fullcalendar

In designing a working reservation page for my facility, one attribute has so far been impossible for me to get.  That is a fixed header which is intended to always be visible and "on top", even if the calendar scrolls into it.  Currently the behavior is that the calendar object scrolls over the header which leads to rather unattractive visuals.  I have tried many work-a-rounds using various div/css settings which are designed to fix this sort of behavior and in in non-FC web pages work perfectly.  The calendar over-rides, things like z-index and blocking settings for the container div's.[[screen shot showing the header with calendar overlapping the header.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XN2lg.png)

Does someone know how to force the calendar to render below a fixed header?  Is this even possible without an overhaul of the CSS files?

Comment: would probably useful to share the HTML/CSS so we can see exactly how you've configured your page. This kind of stuff can be very fiddly.

Answer (score 1):

So I got it working: Proper fiddling was key.  Setting the z-index=-1 on the outermost page container plus careful attention to the layering and positioning of subsequent containers up to and including the calendar itself made it work.

I think my problem was that at first I didn't have a complete handle on the layering of containers in the document and was probably attempting to set the z-index of the outermost container of my header to a large value thinking it would push the header to the top of the stack.

The important CSS and body layout code is partially copied just for inspection

```html
<style>
    /* <!-- Masthead definition --> */    
    .header{ 
      width:100%; 
      position:fixed !important; 
      height:auto; 
      padding-bottom:5px; 
      background:#c8102e; 
      top:50;
    }
 
    /* <!-- Set the main Calendar container to 100% width so that sub-containers can float center --> */
    /* <!-- Set the main Calendar container relative position to help fix its position--> */
    .mainPage {
      width: 100%;
      position:relative;
      top:50; 
      height: auto;
      z-index:-1; /* <!-- push its contents under the Masthead --> */
     }
    
    /* <!-- Set this subcontainer to absolute postion to help force it below Masthead--> */
    /* <!-- maintain 100% width setting --> */
    #calendarme {
      position:absolute;
      overflow:auto;
      width: 100%;
      margin-top: 130px;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
     }

</style>
   <body>
     <!-- Masthead content -->
     <div data-role="page" id="page1">
       <!-- Main Site Name Header imutable kind of -->
       <div data-role="header" id="headerme" class="header">
         <div class="inner-topHeader-panel">
           <h1><center><b>UH SERC-NMR Reservation</b></center></h1>
         </div>  
       </div>  
     </div> 
     <div data-role="page" class="mainPage">  
       <div role="main inner-centercontent" class="ui-content" id="calendarme">   
         <div id="FC-container" class="container" >  
         
         <!-- Calendar -->
           <div id="calendar-div" class="container">
             <div id="Calendar"></div>
           </div> 
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
   </body>
```